# Boto 2.6 CloudSearch "No module named requests" Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm following this tutorial:
http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/cloudsearch_tut.html

I've installed boto 2.6. The command:

```
conn = boto.connect_cloudsearch()
```

produces the error:

```
>>> conn = boto.connect_cloudsearch()Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "boto/__init__.py", line 616, in connect_cloudsearch
    from boto.cloudsearch.layer2 import Layer2
  File "boto/cloudsearch/layer2.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .domain import Domain
  File "boto/cloudsearch/domain.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .document import DocumentServiceConnection
  File "boto/cloudsearch/document.py", line 30, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

How do I find the missing requests module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**requests**](http://docs.python-requests.org/) is a third-party module that is a pre-resquite for that module,  either do:

```
pip install requests
```

or

```
easy_install requests
```

If these don't work for you, [it is on github](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests).

Having this module will then give you access to boto.

Answer (score 2):

At time of writing, 
`boto` (2.8.0) requires a pretty old `requests` module, specifically

```
pip install requests==0.14.2
```

if you use >1.0.0 when using `document.doc_service.commit()` you get

```
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it. On the command line type:

```
easy_install requests
```

Answer (score 0):

The `requests` module is a third party library for simplifying HTTP from Python. Info and installation instructions can be found on PyPi http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests

You should use `pip` to install boto which will download necessary requirements, including `requests`. The other requirements are captured in the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/master/requirements.txt) file in the boto source.

```
pip install boto
```

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that a requests upgrade from 0.14.1 to version 0.14.2 cleared up the issues I was having with a similar error. I was initially confused because most people upgrade boto to 2.4 or higher and fixed the problem.

Just a note - I specifically installed 0.14.2 - not 1.0 or higher, which has its own problems in our setup.